# How to get the unique count of documents in Lucene TopDocs?

Tags: java, lucene

When I ask the property "totalHits" on my TopDocs object, I get the number of hits. 
But I want to know "how many" documents are found, not the "total hits".

Example:

```
- document 1: field A: foo bar - field B: testjes
- document 2: field A: bar foo - field B: foo bar
```

If I search on "foo", I will get 3 results when I ask for "docs.totalHits".
But I want to know the number of documents, which is 2.

I could loop the list and save the "document ID" in a Set. And then ask the size of the Set, but does Lucene support a better way to solve this?

Jochen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocsCollector.html#getTotalHits%28%29) you can retrieve it from your `TopDocCollector` using `getTotalHits()`.

**Edit:** For Example

```
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10, true);
searcher.search(query, collector);
TopDocs topDocs = collector.topDocs();
int numResults = collector.getTotalHits();
```

Comment: Hmm, how do I get to the TopDocCollector object? I'm searching like this: TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, blocksize); count = docs.totalHits;